# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'marksSession' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, intercom

- right now I am passing hard coded value for my name.
- I am trying to pass the dynamic username for my name key inside my scriprt tag from sportsService.
- its working fine in my ts file.
- but its not working fine in my html file.
- I am getting an error. ---> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'marksSession' of undefined
- can you guys tell me how to pass inside script tag of .html.
- providing my code below

**index.html**

```
<script>
    (function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/APP_ID';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()
</script>

<script>
    let players=this.sportsService.marksSession();
    console.log("players--->" + players);
    if(players) {
        this.userId = players.user_players.SSO[0];
    }

    Intercom('trackEvent', 'share-link');

    window.intercomSettings = {
        app_id: 'APP_ID',
        name: "Jane Doe", // Full name
        email: "customer@example.com", // Email address
        created_at: 1312182000 // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
    };
</script>
```

**sports.ts**

```
import { sportsService } from '../../services/sports.service';

constructor(public sportsService : sportsService){

}

ngOnInit() {    

        let that =this;
        let players=this.sportsService.marksSession();
        if(players) {
            this.userId = players.user_players.SSO[0];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import your TypeScript file on your HTML page, that should take care of the TypeError you're getting. I believe you will need to compile your TypeScript to JavaScript prior to doing this.

Check out W3Schools for some info on how to use the  tag in your HTML:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply...can you update in my code its so confusing :(

Comment: @arar Google is your best resource to figuring out how to do things. I recommend Googling "compiling typescript to Javascript" for some step-by-step tutorials. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html has a great example of how to include the JS file in your HTML. Don't be afraid to read through documentation! Sometimes the best tips and tricks you can get are in a language's documentation. This is especially true for JS-based languages.